# Cisco 6rd configuration example - ipv6 general-prefix

Tags: cisco, ipv6

I'm currently learning the IPv6 tunneling via IPv4 in GNS3. I've done manual tunnels, 6to4 and now I'm tackling 6rd.
I've read on the subject and I think I get the whole concept..The IPv6 prefix, the common IPv4 suffix/prefix etc.
Then I've read a config example on the web [>>here<<](http://docwiki.cisco.com/w/index.php?title=6rd_Configuration_Example&oldid=48585#CE). What I have hard time to comprehend is the whole `ipv6 general-prefix` options. Could someone explain these two lines from the CE config?

- ipv6 general-prefix DELEGATED_PREFIX 6rd Tunnel0
- ipv6 address DELEGATED_PREFIX ::/128 anycast (on int Tunnel 0)

maybe this as well:

- ipv6 address DELEGATED_PREFIX ::/64 eui-64 (on int Ethernet 0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ipv6 general-prefix DELEGATED_PREFIX 6rd Tunnel0
```

This line defines `DELEGATED_PREFIX`. It automatically calculates the IPv6 prefix based on the 6rd settings of the `Tunnel0` interface.

```
ipv6 address DELEGATED_PREFIX ::/128 anycast (on int Tunnel 0)
```

This line sets an IPv6 address on the `Tunnel0` interface using the `DELEGATED_PREFIX` defined before. It tells the router to take the prefix, leave the other bits zero (`::`) and configure it as a single anycast address. The `anycast` flag tells the router that the address may be used on multiple devices at the same time. It will therefore not perform any Duplicate Address Detection (not really relevant for a tunnel interface) and it will not use that address as a source address (because the return traffic might end up at one of the other anycast nodes).

```
ipv6 address DELEGATED_PREFIX ::/64 eui-64 (on int Ethernet 0)
```

This does the same for the `Ethernet0` interface. It uses the `DELEGATED_PREFIX` to give an address to the interface. One problem is that you're using the same subnet on the tunnel interface. You should use separate subnets for different interfaces. The `eui-64` flag tells the router to generate the last 64 bits of the interface address based on its MAC address.

An example to (hopefully) make things clearer:

Let's take the 6rd settings from the example:

- 6rd IPv4 prefix: 10.0.0.0/8
- 6rd IPv6 prefix: 2001:db80::/28

Then if your router has IPv4 address `10.0.0.10` you will get IPv6 prefix `2001:db80:0:a000::/52`. The `/8` in the IPv4 prefix means that the first 8 bits are fixed. So when constructing the IPv6 prefix it will only use the last 24 (32 - 8) bits from the IPv4 address. These have binary value `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010`. When written in hexadecimal that is `00 00 0a`. This is appended to the `/28` IPv6 prefix, giving a `/52` (28 + 24).

So `DELEGATED_PREFIX` will get value `2001:db80:0:a000::/52`. Therefore the `Tunnel0` interface will get address `2001:db80:0:a000::/128` and the `Ethernet0` interface will get something like `2001:db80:0:a000:1234:56ff:fe78:90ab/64` (assuming MAC address `12.34.56.78.90.ab`).

It would be better to give the ethernet interface an address from a different subnet, like:

```
ipv6 address DELEGATED_PREFIX 0:0:0:1::/64 eui-64
```

That would result in `2001:db80:0:a001:1234:56ff:fe78:90ab/64`. And if you don't want to make the address dependent on the MAC address you can also just give it a fixed address:

```
ipv6 address DELEGATED_PREFIX 0:0:0:1::1/64
```

That would result in `2001:db80:0:a001::1/64`.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! In case of the anycast tunnel address: you wrote, that it won't use that address as source for obvious reason. My question is: what address would be used as source address in that case?

Comment: One more question: `ipv6 address DELEGATED_PREFIX 0:0:0:1::1/64`. If I want to use DELEGATED_PREFIX, I have to set it's 'placeholder' bits to 0? Like the first 3 zeros in 0:0:0:1::1/64 are 'placeholders' as 'here goes the value of DELEGATED_PREFIX'? What would happen if I were to specifiy a non-zero value on those places?

Comment: If it sends it to a link-local address it will use the link-local address from the outgoing interface. Those are always present on any IPv6 interface. If it initiated traffic to a global address it will If the router initiates traffic it will not use an anycast address. It will take an address of a different interface instead. If it doesn't have a global address at all then it won't be able to communicate. This is a simplified explanation as the full algorithm is much more complex. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6724 for the full algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure what will happen if there are conflicting bits in the delegated prefix and the interface configuration. I'll have to try that ☺